# Fortify file (.fpr file) to PDF convertion

Tags: code-coverage, fortify

Basically I am trying to generate the PDF file from the Fortify report file which is in .fpr formate.

Can any one suggest me some utility tool which can be accessed by the .bat file.

I am trying to execute the following command :

i.e,.. `ReportGenerator -format pdf -f MyProject.pdf -source MyProject.fpr`

Can anyone help me to generate the PDF file from the .fpr file??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could not run the Report Generator. When I run the above command it is showing like command not found. In windows it shows as not recognized as internal or external command. Help me to instal the utility on my windows OS. Is there any utility for Windows to run this ReportGenerator?

Comment: Do you have Fortify Installed on the machine you want to run?  When Fortify Installs it adds its 'bin' folder to the Windows Path.  Sounds like that is not done.

Answer (score 12):

There is a command-line utility to generate an Report from the FPR file.

Currently there are two report generators: Legacy and BIRT. The BIRT report engine was introduced into Audit Workbench with version 4.40.

Here is an example using the BIRT Report engine to generate a DISA STIG report

```
BIRTReportGenerator -template "DISA STIG" -source HelloWorld_second.fpr 
-output BirtReport.pdf -format PDF -showSuppressed --Version "DISA STIG 3.9" 
-UseFortifyPriorityOrder
```

*The different versions are specified in the SCA Users Guide.*

Using the legacy one is a little more involved. The command is:

```
ReportGenerator -format pdf -f LegacyReport.pdf -source HelloWorld_second.fpr 
-template DisaStig3.10.xml -showSuppressed -showHidden
```

You can either use one of the predefined template reports located in the /Core/config/reports directory or generate one using the Report Wizard and saving the template which gets stored in the `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Fortify\config\AWB-XX.XX\reports\` directory in Windows.

On Linux/Mac look at the configuration file `<SCA Install Dir>/Core/config/fortify.properties` for the `com.fortify.WorkingDirectory` property, this is where the reports will be stored

Answer (score 0):

Report generator is part of Audit workbench installation. Please make sure to install Audit workbench as part of Fortify SCA installation.